# JavaScript execution exceeded timeout - jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, debugging, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, cdn

I've created a mobile app based on the jquery mobile framework.

I'm using wordpress as cms.

All seems to work fine. But after a while of navigating backwards and forwards round the app, suddenly the buttons become unclickable with this javascript error.

> JavaScript Error on Line 16
>   http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js
>   JavaScript execution exceeded timeout

What does this error roughly mean and why does it not happen instantly? And how come its an error within jQuery it's self, never seen this happen before?

My experience with javascript errors are if it's wrong/broken in the first place then you get an error straight away.

The error kicks in mainly when navigating through archive pages that contain big lists.

I understand its almost impossible to say what it is if you can't see the app or play with it - but has any one experienced similar java script errors?

When the error sometimes appears, you can still use the app, but sometimes it locks it up completely.

Any thoughts would be most helpful - as I'm desperately needing a fix

Also I'm viewing it Mobile Safari on iPhone 3GS
**Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_5 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8L1**

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to the latest build of jQM which is now in Beta 3

Comment: I agree with Phill; jQuery Mobile Beta 3 has dome size management functionality that will help your mobile website not get too memory-heavy and crash devices.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will upgrade at the weekend and see what the results are - but bizarrely I think I tried upgrading already with the latest jqm, and for some reason, it scaled my app really small in the mobile browser, like it was a 960px wide.. weird! If it still does the same scaling on upgrade, I will try and test it anyway to see if the error goes, and then fix visual problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like it's a Safari mobile bug.

Just been getting the same javascript exception with a couple of other popular, javascript intensive, libraries on iOS5.

The exception occurs occasionaly when I use the scrollability library and pdf.js. Even the example pages for these libraries cause my iPad every now and again to cast this exception.

I'm using an iPad 2 with the first stable iOs 5 release.

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3

Comment: I updated to the RC1 jquery mobile and it seemed to stop this error occurring, have not been able recreate such error since on iOS version 4.3.5

Comment: Same problem here, using iPad3. Other devices and browsers working fine with my code only the safari browser on this device does not. It is a shame! Any idea what to do to temporarily fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The list looks to be taking too long to process and the browser is killing it (the scripts) off, but there could be other contributing factors.

Post some code and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'm a little behind with other work so will try and post some code at the weekend. Sounds logical what your saying but yeh could be buggy else where.

Answer (score 0):

Only a pointer, perhaps in the right direction:

I'm getting the same error, when I'm initiating a transition while the previous transition still seems in process. If I wait for the transition to finish (and the screen "to settle") and then do the next transition, everything is fine. However if I trigger the next transition before finishing the last, I'm also getting this error.

There is a transitioningqueue in JQM, maybe an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your device. Also, consider loading jQuery and jQuery mobile at the end of your script:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script> 

<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery.widget || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.mobile.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

I was getting "JavaScript execution exceeded timeout" on my iPhone 4S right after jQuery mobile 1.0 loaded and ran for the first time in a head script element. Restarting my phone fixed it, so in my case, it seemed to be a bug with iOS5 Mobile Safari.

I haven't tried the above but maybe giving the script a second chance to run would do the trick - might even try injecting the script element in the DOM like Facebook and Google Analytics recommend doing rather than using document write.